# How can I handle a GET request from an external source in symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I am trying to process a GET request in symfony 4 with a JSON  response of some kind of string array. How can I handle the request in my Symfony 4 app? Do I use a controller or a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to first decide your code structure and stick to it.
It a advisable to use Controller which gives you extra benefits by extending AbstractController.php.

A controller is a PHP function you create that reads information from the Request object and creates and returns a Response object. The response could be an HTML page, JSON, XML, a file download, a redirect, a 404 error or anything else. The controller executes whatever arbitrary logic your application needs to render the content of a page. [Source](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller.html)

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class TestController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(path="test", name="test", methods={"GET"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $test['a'] = 'A';
        $test['b'] = 'B';
        $test['c'] = 'C';

        return new JsonResponse($test);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!